# Capybara errors in remote environment only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, capybara, rspec-rails, codeship

I am trying to automate feature tests using rspec/Capybara in Rails when pushing commits to GitHub. It seems not find the form elements, double checked the ID and tested without the `within` helper. The tests run and pass without issue when running locally. However, using the same Capybara driver, they fail when running the automated tests, showing:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#new_user"
```

When executing in GitHub, the following appears when the run command begins (unsure if this has any importance to this issue):

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly
```

in my spec_helper.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
    options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1400,1400')

   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end
 
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10

Capybara.configure do |config|
   config.javascript_driver = :chrome_headless
end
```

Full Screenshot of errors:
[image]
[image]

Update 8/18/2020. I am now using the following configuration in `spec_helper.rb` and it is not finding select boxes. Now working on implenting Codeship, I am seeing the same error.

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_headless_chrome do |app|
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(loggingPrefs: { browser: 'ALL' })
    opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  
    chrome_args = %w[--headless --window-size=1920,1080 --no-sandbox]
    chrome_args.each { |arg| opts.add_argument(arg) }
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: opts, desired_capabilities: caps)
  end

  Capybara.configure do |config|
    # change this to :chrome to observe tests in a real browser
    config.default_max_wait_time = 10 # seconds
    config.javascript_driver = :selenium_headless_chrome
  end
```

Comment: Are the `select` boxes it’s not finding actually &lt;select> elements or are they JS widget replacements?

Comment: In the view, they are ```<%= select_tag....%>``` and not Javascript elements. The test is running:
```select(@foo, :from => 'bar')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved:**
Using `puts page.body`, the output showed that it was displaying a template error. After some troubleshooting it was determined that the error was happening because of the **application.js** manifest being empty and assets not precompiling. After adding `yarn install` then `rails assets:precompile` in the **tests.yml** file (for GitHub actions) or project settings in Codeship, everything worked as expected. The full list of setup commands is:
`rvm use 2.5.8 --install`
`gem install bundler:2.1.4`
`bundle install`
`yarn install`
`rails assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

Debugging CI tests can be extremely hard. Have you considered using something like CircleCI? It offers the ability to log in to the remote container, and also port forwarding to a local browser to debug tests.

Also have you considered using screenshots (artifacts on CCI) to capture an image of the screen at fail time? The gem [capybara-screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot) can be useful for this.

Just some ideas...

Comment: The reason for the error was that assets were not precompiling. I posted the solution in this thread. Thank you though. I will look into capybara-screenshot as it would have helped resolve this issue quicker.